# Conditional formatting based on ranking values from another column

Tags: google-sheets, gs-conditional-formatting

I've created a Google Sheets spreadsheet that automatically tallies scores. In the Total column (V), I've used conditional formatting to rank the teams from most to least points using colours.

[image: Image of the spreadsheet for context]

[Link to spreadsheet (comment-only)](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-nmw4Z_1emflAsBkqByVCEIj43YYuEwWZRvLIVGKFdE/edit?usp=sharing)

I would like to conditionally format the first column (A) based on the values of V, or transfer the conditional formatting from A to V automatically, so that **the colours of A are the same as V**. However, I'm not sure how to do so: I've tried pasting the conditional formatting from A into V, which doesn't work. I've seen examples of conditional formatting based on logical operators applied to other cells/columns, but I don't think that's applicable here.

Any guidance would be appreciated!

Comment: Google Sheets is not programming issue, please search in another places

Answer (score 0):

By using the the Google Scripts, you can apply the following two scripts to your sheet to achieve what you want.

First, OnEdit() for when new data is added in column V.

```
function onEdit(e) { //When a cell is edited
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var cellColumn = e.range.getColumn(); // Cell column that was edited
  var cellRow = e.range.getRow(); //Cell row that was edited

  if(cellColumn == 22){ //If the edited cell is in column 22 i.e. column V
    var editedCellBackground = ss.getActiveSheet().getRange(cellRow, cellColumn).getBackground(); //get color of cell in column V
    ss.getActiveSheet().getRange(cellRow, 1).setBackground(editedCellBackground); //set color of A to corresponding color in column V
  }else{ //if the edited cell is not in column V
    //do nothing
  }
}
```

Second, OnOpen() for when data is already in the sheet, it should be formatted when the sheet is opened. The name of the sheet may need to be changed, as it is currently set as "Sheet1".

```
function onOpen() { //when sheet is open
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var row = 1;

  while(ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1").getRange(row, 22).getValue() != ""){ //while there is another row with data in column V (given by 22)
    var cellBackground = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1").getRange(row, 22).getBackground(); //get value of color in column V
    ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1").getRange(row, 1).setBackground(cellBackground); //set color value of column A to corresponding value of V
    row++; //go to next row
  }
}
```